# C# Query WindowCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having elementary problem with trying to query System.Windows.WindowCollection at some point in my code i have

```
WindowCollection z =   Application.Current.Windows;
```

and would like to do z.Any();

Comment: What is your problem? Explain more..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of [WindowCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) is as follows

```
public sealed class WindowCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

As you may see, it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<Window>`, so in order to have access to the most of the `Enumerable` extension methods, you need first to use [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) like this

```
z.Cast<Window>().Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ works only with `IEnumerable<T>` interface. WindowCollection impliments only `IEnumerable`. There two options:

- `Cast<T>()` - this return IEnumerable but if collection has element which can't be casted to T exception will thrown.
- `OfType<T>()` - this returns IEnumerable. It skips element which can't be casted to T, that is why I prefer OfType.

`Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Any();`